# Display and order a number of results from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I want to display and order a number of results to my webpage.

I'm still a starter with PHP but I have the following code to echo (all) data and that works pretty fine but I don't know if the code is good if I only want to show for example 5 results. And if that would work, how could I order them? (Like a top 5 for quickest time scores)

```
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT name, company, time FROM tablename';

mysql_select_db('databasename');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
    die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM))
{
    echo 
        "name: {$row[0]}  <br> ".
        "company: {$row[1]} <br> ".
        "time: {$row[3]} <br> "
    ;
}
mysql_free_result($retval);
mysql_close($conn);
```

I should somewhere add ORDER BY but can't find the right solution.

Comment: i think you was looking for this `SELECT name, company, time FROM tablename ORDER BY columnname LIMIT 5`

Comment: Add it with the query

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated ... please try to use `mysqli_*` or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, company, `time` FROM tablename   ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT 5';
```

Comment: i already tried something like this but then it didn't work, somewhere I made a mistake because this one works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = 'SELECT name, company, time FROM table name';` should be

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, company, time FROM table name ORDER BY column_name ACS | DESC';
```

Take a lot at the docs [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp).

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this also works (like the answer of Krish), but I was searching for the limit too so I need to choose his answer as the right one this time, I'm sorry! Thanks for the link to the docs!

Answer (score 0):

`$sql = SELECT name, company, time FROM tablename ORDERBY columnname LIMIT n;`

Here n refers to number of records to be shown.